# C++ Type of variables - value

Tags: c++, variables, types

I am the beginner, but I think same important thinks I should learn as soon as it possible.
So I have a code:

```
float fl=8.28888888888888888888883E-5;
cout<<"The value = "<<fl<<endl;
```

But my .exe file after run show:

```
8.2888887845911086e-005
```

I suspected the numbers to limit of the type and rest will be the zero, but I saw digits, which are random. Maybe it gives digits from memory after varible?
Could you explain me how it does works?

Comment: What every ... about floats etc. ([link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html))

Comment: We are floating point of borg. Accuracy is irrelevant, you will be approximated.

Comment: http://www.exploringbinary.com/floating-point-questions-are-endless-on-stackoverflow-com/

Answer (score 3):

> I suspected the numbers to limit of the type and rest will be the zero

Yes, this is exactly what happens, but it happens in binary. This program will show it by using the hexadecimal printing format `%a`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int c, char *v[]) {
  float fl = 8.28888888888888888888883E-5;

  printf("%a\n%a\n", 8.28888888888888888888883E-5, fl);
}
```

It shows:

```
0x1.5ba94449649e2p-14
0x1.5ba944p-14
```

In these results, `0x1.5ba94449649e2p-14` is the hexadecimal representation of the `double` closest to 8.28888888888888888888883*10<sup>-5</sup>, and `0x1.5ba944p-14`
 is the representation of the conversion to `float` of that number. As you can see, the conversion simply truncated the last digits (in this case. The conversion is done according to the rounding mode, and when the rounding goes up instead of down, it changes one or more of the last digits).

When you observe what happens in **decimal**, the fact that `float` and `double` are **binary** floating-point formats on your computer means that there are extra digits in the representation of the value.

Answer (score 2):

> I suspected the numbers to limit of the type and rest will be the zero

That is what happens internally.  Excess bits beyond what the type can store are lost.

But that's in the binary representation.  When you convert it to decimal, you can get trailing non-zero digits.

Example:

`0b0.00100` is `0.125` in decimal

Answer (score 1):

What you're seeing is a result of the fact that you cannot exactly represent a floating-point number in memory. Because of this, floats will be stored as the nearest value that can be stored in memory. A float usually has 24 bits used to represent the mantissa, which translates to about 6 decimal places (this is implementation defined though, so you shouldn't rely on this). When printing more than 6 decimal digits, you'll notice your value isn't stored in memory as the value you intended, and you'll see random digits.

So to recap, the problem you encountered is caused by the fact that base-10 decimal numbers cannot be represented in memory, instead the closest number to it is stored and this number will then be used.

Answer (score 0):

each data type has range after this range all number is from memory or rubbish so you have to know this ranges and deal with it when you write code.
you can know this ranges from [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/44774/) or [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3f49ktz.aspx)

Comment: Your first link says that the range for `float` goes from 1.8E-38 to 3.4E+38. Shouldn't 8.28888888888888888888883E-5 be within the limits?

Comment: i just want to make you know that limit isn't just two number limit your number but it is also the number of digits after decimal point .. so if you just try it as double you can see it show the whole number.
so add to your knowledge every data type has many limits you have to know it to be a good programmer.

Comment: `#include <iostream>

#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

void main()

{

 float fl=8.28888888888888888888883E-5;
 cout<<"The value = "<<setprecision(17)<<fl<<endl;
 double f2=8.28888888888888888888883E-5;
 cout<<"The value = "<<setprecision(17)<<f2<<endl;
 system("pause");
}`